# I get a blank screen when debugging a program in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012

Now what happens(after editing code) is whenever I type in more than one word, it has spasms. Any fixes? Thanks. Sorry if I seem like I don't know anything. Expensive books and nobody to teach me has me reading tutorials online. (The edited code is below.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string qu;

int y;

int main()
{
y = 1;
while (y == 1)
{
    cout << "Welcome to the magic 8-ball application." <<"\nAsk a yes or no question, and the 8-ball will answer." << "\n";
    cin >> qu;
    cout << "\nProccessing...\nProccessing...\nProccessing...";
    cout << "The answer is...: ";
    int ans = (int)(rand() % 6) + 1;
    if (ans == 1)
        cout << "Probably not.";
    if (ans == 2)
        cout << "There's a chance.";
    if (ans == 3)
        cout << "I don't think so.";
    if (ans == 4)
        cout << "Totally!";
    if (ans == 5)
        cout << "Not a chance!";
    if (ans == 6)
        cout << "75% chance.";
    system("CLS");
    cout << "\nWant me to answer another question?" << "(1 = yes, 2 = no.)";
    cin >> y;
    }

return 0;

}
```

Comment: What did the code do before? What are you expecting it to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 while (y = 1);
```

should be

```
 while (y == 1)
```

You have extra `;` and should use `==`.

Comment: Thank you taocp, I now have another problem.

Comment: @Rand0mCoder Do you mean when you input more than one word in a line to `qu`? `cin>>qu` by default stops reading at whitespace, try to use `getline(cin,qu)` instead.

Comment: Getline worked, but now when I answer yes for the loop, it goes on with no question, like I just pressed enter without entering anything.

Comment: @Rand0mCoder add `cin.ignore()` after `cin >>y` at bottom of your while loop

Comment: Great! Thanks for everything tao.

Answer (score 0):

There's infinite loop here:

```
while (y = 1);
```

Delete `;`. Also `y == 1`, not `y = 1`.

---

To avoid these errors in future:

1) Inverse comparison this way:

```
while (1 == y)
```

Now if you type `=` instead of `==` then your code doesn't compile because `1 = y` is invalid.

Though most compilers warn you if you make assignment in condition. You shouldn't ignore compiler warnings.

2) Put opening brace on the same line:

```
while (1 == y) {
// ...... some code
}
```

Now if you type `;` in the end of line then your code remains correct:

```
while (1 == y) {;
// ...... some code
}
```

Comment: Inverted comparisons. Yuck!

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan Added note about compiler warning